# HttpContext AbsolutePath goes to wrong URL for aliased pages - C#

Tags: url, path, request, alias, httpcontext

On my website each page has links that are created in the codebehind, where the links are the current URL with one query parameter changed. To do this, I've been using this method (this specific example is for the pagination):

```
var queryValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString());
queryValues.Set("page", num);
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
string updatedQueryString = "?" + queryValues.ToString();
string newUrl = url + updatedQueryString;
return newUrl;
```

This worked on my local version fine. However, when I created each page in Ektron and added a manual alias, the URLs generated still went to the file location in the solution. For example, my original page was /WebAssets/Templates/EventListView.aspx. I created the page in Ektron as /Alumni/Events/List. I can go to /Alumni/Events/List, but then when I click on a page button the page that loads is /WebAssets/Templates/EventListView.aspx?page=2 instead of /Alumni/Events/List/?page=2

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution:

```
var rawUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
var url = rawUrl.Split('?')[0];
string newUrl = url + updatedQueryString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `QuickLink` property of the primary contentblock for /Alumni/Events/List, this will be the alias use want to use for your page links or for redirects to the same page.  This is probably `ContentData.QuickLink` if you're already loading the ContentData at some point in the code.

Notes:

1. Aliasing may remove your "page" querystring parameter by default, to resolve this issue, edit your alias in the Workarea to have a "Query String Action" of "Append".
2. Make sure you preprend a "/" to the QuickLink value (if it's not absolute and not prepended already) if using it on the frontend, otherwise your links will bring you to something like /Alumni/Events/List/Alumni/Events/List?page=2, which is no good.